# Add Row to DataGrid if ItemSource Binding returns no data

Tags: wpf, xaml

is there any simple solution to this problem..first i thought i can create an empty ObservableCollection and writte:

```
ObservableCollection<PersonDetailsView> newOCollection= new ObservableCollection<PersonDetailsView>();
myDataGrid.ItemsSource=newOCollection.ToArray();
```

and it works..i get an empty row..but the problem is that i loose the other binding..is there any way to Bind to newOCollection only if my `{Binding Person}` (see the code) doesn't return a value

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" IsReadOnly="False" BorderBrush="#FFCCCCCC"  
        GridLinesVisibility="All" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Person}" Background="White" Margin="10,45,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="91" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        HeadersVisibility="None" SelectionMode="Single" Name="dtaPersons" Width="415">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Person.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Person.Surname, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Button  Style="{DynamicResource ChromelessButtonStyle}" Content="r" FontFamily="Marlett" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ObservableCollection<PersonDetailsView> newOCollection= new ObservableCollection<PersonDetailsView>();

if (!myDataGrid.Items.Any())
    myDataGrid.ItemsSource=newOCollection.ToArray();
```

Comment: Where does Any() comes from?

Comment: @Georg `Using System.Linq`

Comment: @Bridge i do use System.Linq but Any() is not listed